# Trying to find examples of drop-down div using ionic and bootstrap frameworks

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework

i'm looking for div with some toggle, which is moving out by a click, I am looking for a long time div like this, on photo is example what i'm looking for, thank you for the attention.[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is easily achieved. I will use a example from a app I built. What you are going to want to do is use a ng-show. So when the item is clicked the rest of the content is shown and when it is clicked again the the content is hidden. so say for instance you have a list (it can be ng-repeated or not)

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="item" ng-click="toggle = !toggle">
        <h3>Content</h3>
        <p ng-show="toggle" >Here it the rest of the content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

then in your controller:

```
.controller('main', function($scope){

  $scope.toggle = true;
})
```

You can see what it looks like here: http://play.ionic.io/app/6f7792a3e45d

also if you want to add some cool animations look at [ng-fx](https://github.com/Hendrixer/ngFx) so that when it is hidden or shown it will have a cool enter and leave animation.

Comment: Thanks @Jess Patton, your advice is very useful)